# xorg: 2 keyboards with different layouts

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard

I've been trying to configure my laptop, so that the builtin keyboard is in portuguese and my usb keyboard is in english (international). I have been doing some research and got to a solution that works perfectly well when the usb keyboard is plugged in after the xorg server is started. In this situation both keyboards have their respective layouts. But if I start the xorg server with the usb keyboard plugged in, both keyboards end up with the english layout.

Right now my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-keyboard.conf` is the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchProduct "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbModel" "abnt2"
    Option "XkbLayout" "br"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "usb-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchProduct "Evision RGB Keyboard"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc104"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option "XkbVariant" "altgr-intl"
EndSection
```

I really don't understand why it works well when I start the xorg server and then plug in the usb keyboard, but it doesn't work when I start the xorg server with the usb keyboard already plugged in.

I have tried breaking the config in 2 separate files `30-system-keyboard.conf` and `40-usb-keyboard.conf` so that one config is loaded afther the other one, but the result is the same.

Can someone please help me fix this, so that it works in all situations?

Setting the layouts via `setxkbmap -device ID` doesn't work because the IDs change.

Comment: My situation is similar but in the oppisite direction: I‌ want all keyboards I might attach to the laptop have a specific layout (`de`), but only the laptop's internal keyboard should have another layout (`us`). I have created first a configuration that matches all keyboards and sets layout `de`, and later a configuration that matches the `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` and sets layout `us`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need that I could solve with an `udev` rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-keyboard.rules`:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="keyboard_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="input", GOTO="keyboard_end"
KERNEL!="event*", GOTO="keyboard_end"

ENV{ID_INPUT_KEY}=="?*", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2003", ENV{XKBMODEL}="pc105", ENV{XKBLAYOUT}="fr", ENV{XKBVARIANT}="oss", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}="nbsp:level3n,lv3:ralt_switch,compose:menu,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

LABEL="keyboard_end"
```

It works fine when the keyboard is plugged before X is started.

You’ll have to duplicate the main line, replace the `idVendor` and `idProduct` values with those of your keyboards and `XKBMODEL`, `XKBLAYOUT`, `XKBVARIANT` and `XKBOPTIONS` parameters with the values that match the mapping you want to use.