# Using different layout for each keyboard

Tags: shell-script, systemd, udev, keyboard-layout

I've seen similar questions here, but I don't think I'm duplicating any of them. I've been making progress on this matter for years, but there's still some way to go. The latest stage is that I use udev rules below to (1) apply a certain keyboard layout when my external keyboard is connected, and (2) revert back when it's disconnected.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="09da", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2403", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{XKBMODEL}="pc105", ENV{XKBLAYOUT}="tr", ENV{XKBVARIANT}="f", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}=""
ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{idVendor}=="09da", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2403", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{XKBMODEL}="pc105", ENV{XKBLAYOUT}="tr", ENV{XKBVARIANT}="", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}=""
```

However, as it is, this unfortunately seems to apply the keyboard layout specified for that external keyboard **globally**, instead of applying it specifically to that keyboard only. As a result of this, the integrated laptop keyboard becomes virtually unusable unless another step is taken to fix this, which can be done by a shell script containing the following:

```
int_kbd_id="$(xinput -list | grep " AT Translated Set 2 keyboard " | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')"
ext_kbd_id="$(xinput -list | grep " COMPANY 2.4G Device   " | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')"
if [[ "$int_kbd_id" ]]; then
    setxkbmap -device "$int_kbd_id" -layout "tr" -variant ""
fi
if [[ "$ext_kbd_id" ]]; then
    setxkbmap -device "$ext_kbd_id" -layout "tr" -variant "f"
fi
```

Now, I need to get this script executed automatically after the udev rule above is executed at least for the first time during a session (and before user login, so that both keyboards can be used during login). I've noticed that if the external keyboard is disconnected and re-connected after running this script, the integrated laptop keyboard layout is not changed again (but I'm not sure how stable/reliable this behavior is).

So far, my three attempts to execute it using (1) the udev rule with `RUN+="/usr/local/bin/<SCRIPT>"`, (2) `/etc/xdg/autostart/keyboard-layouts.desktop`, and (3) `/etc/systemd/system/keyboard-layouts.service` have all failed. The modified udev rule somehow made both keyboards totally unusable, and the others made no effect - perhaps because the script was executed before the udev rule, because the systemd service was not properly configured using options like "Before=", "After=" etc...

Comment: I’m very surprised that the configuration you specified through `udev` gets applied globally. I’ve been using a similar configuration for years. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752082/219302 for my answer to another question by someone with a similar need.

Comment: Oh, you've got a more complex structure. Hoping that it will work as expected, I've just copied it, merely changing  vendor and product ids as well as `{XKBLAYOUT}="tr", ENV{XKBVARIANT}="f", ENV{XKBOPTIONS}=""`, but unfortunately it didn't work. Could it be because my system is Debian Testing or some hardware issue/incompatibility?